# How to store/retrieve text/file data to firebase database in the flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to  store text data and image url and pdf url etc to firebase data base and retrieve back the same data again in the flutter application .

Please help me achieve this UI and functionality as well, using firebase storage or cloud firestore or any database..
Please go through the UI attached here
I want the images or pdfs uploaded to the firebase store etc to be displayed in the form page itself.[image: UI screenshot]

If it is possible with cloud firestore also . It is ok for me.  I want to fetch the imaage url and pdf url to download the image and pdf in the same form page.

I want to achieve the above UI along with the functionality. Which  do you suggest "firebase database" or     " cloud firestore". I have stored text data and date into cloud firestore using    below code in models/entry.dart

```
    class Entry {

   String entryId;
    String cattegorry;
   String companyname;
   String modelname;
  String seriesname;
  String year;
  String serielnumber;
   String date;
-
-
-
  String website;

  Entry({ this.cattegorry,this.companyname,this.modelname,this.seriesname,this.year,this.serielnumber,this.date-----------this.website, @required this.entryId});

 factory Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Entry(

        cattegorry: json['cattegorry'],
       
      companyname: json['companyname'],
      modelname: json['modelname'],
      seriesname: json['seriesname'],
      year: json['year'],
      serielnumber: json['serielnumber'],
        date: json['date'],
     -------
        entryId: json['entryId']
    );
  }
 Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    return {

      'cattegorry':cattegorry,
    
      'companyname': companyname,
     'modelname': modelname,
      'seriesname': seriesname,
      'year': year,
      'serielnumber':serielnumber,
      'date': date,
     '----------
      'entryId':entryId
    };
  }
}
```

and remaining  in screens/entry.dart  and entryprovider.dart  . I have folowed MyJournal Appplication of firestore crud example.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: Yes I have  succesfully uploaded text data and date with date picker into cloud firestore and able to retrieve  all the data. I have also uploaded  image from camera and device gallery to firebase storage using camera plugin and image picker.. I am able to retrieve all the uploaded images to   one  single container or path,  and all the pdfs into one single conatiner/path.\But where as my requirement is different.

Comment: I have multiple  devices in my application , I have to create a form page for each devcie that user has to give the device deatils, images, user documents in pdf and image format.He should be able to check all the details   like text,image and pdf  in single form page  for each devcie.

Comment: implemented  the blow two  code links or solutions in my application                                          https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDrLaajtxLc&t=3s                                                   and                                                                                                                                              https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WppXt57ygI&t=439s

Comment: and                                                                                                                                       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30L5-3eQPK4&t=274s

Comment: Hi waitig for somebody to anser and fix my issue

Comment: Your question is too broad, since you are basically asking for a solution without sharing any of the code you already have or your firestore structure, which makes it hard to guess what you want to achieve and how. So please share your current code (related to this issue only) and your firestore structure.

Comment: I want to achieve the above UI along with the functionality. Which  do you suggest "firebase database" or     " cloud firestore".

Comment: Please share your contact email etc I will share my full code. As I have said I have followed journal application https://github.com/nhandrew/journal_app_2

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that since contact information is PII and should not be shared in Stack Overflow as you can see on this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186065/how-to-handle-personal-information-posted-by-a-user-on-stack-overflow). Regarding your code, I would recommend that you try building it by yourself first, as there is plenty of information on how to integrate firestore with flutter online and on other Stack posts, I recommend you start by checking [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I).

Comment: Thank you very much. There is no probleme with firesstore or firebase setup with flutter. My query is How to save image url, pdfurl into firestore or firebase database and download back agin  the pdf and iage in the flutter application. Please help on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034428/retrieve-one-field-from-firebase-and-display-it-in-a-text-widget Use answers for here 