# Retrieve one field from firebase and display it in a Text Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving a user's first name from firestore, store it in a variable and then trying to display it using a Text Widget.
The database query works for sure because I print it's outcome.
On the other hand, the variable used to store the data is used in the Text widget but it's not displaying anything.

homepage.dart

```
//get the specific document I need
DocumentReference userName = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

//Variable used to store the name
String firstName = '';

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//Get specific field from a document
    userName.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      firstName = ds['firstName'];
      print(firstName);
    });
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Homepage'),
      ),
body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
              ),
              child: Text(firstName)),
```

Any tips?
[image: Image with the database structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call it in init state; otherwise, you can call it by using `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userName.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      firstName = ds['firstName'];
      print(firstName);
    });
  }
```

**Updated**

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: userName.get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['firstName']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    )
```

For more, you can read this article https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Comment: It doesn't work with initState(). I tried it.

Comment: what was the output?

Comment: no output, but i noticed that if I refresh the widget it shows up, is there anyway I can refresh the page before displaying it?

Comment: you can try with `setState`

Comment: how do I do that? just put the above code in the setState?

Comment: just put `firstName = ds['firstName']; ` in setstate; but i will recommend you to use stream or Future builder

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: updated my answer please look at with the future builder

Comment: It worked thank you, I used the initState() along with the FutureBuilder

Comment: I think there would need some tweaking, I didn't run it on my machine. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this in your initState**

*so, the data will be fetched before the build function run and you can acces "firstName" inside Text widget*

```
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState()async {
   await DocumentReference userName = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
userName.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      var firstName = snapshot.docs["firstName"];
       });
    super.initState();
     }
```

if you put the full code i will run the code and show the desired output in my emulator

Thank you

Comment: I get an error initState() returned a future, it must be void without an async keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StreamBuilder` like the following.

```
StreamBuilder<Object>( stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
    .doc(loggedInUser!.displayName)
    .snapshots(),
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData &&
        snapshot.data!
            .data()!
            .containsKey('firstName') &&
        _status) {
      var userName = snapshot.data['firstName'];
      return Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFEAE9EE),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "${userName}",
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

You must use `AsyncSnapshot` as type of Snapshot to get the data property of the data retrieved. You also would want to return another widget in case the `if` condition is `false`.