# Flutter - display field - name - of user that is logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to display name of user that is currently logged in app. I have this code right now but its showing me "Document does not exist". I have it from other person that was asking here on stackoverflow but they figured it somehow but didnt post the full correct code so im asking here again. Link [Retrieve one field from firebase and display it in a Text Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034428/retrieve-one-field-from-firebase-and-display-it-in-a-text-widget)

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
 }

 class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
 DocumentReference userName = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

 //Variable used to store the name
 String name = '';

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
userName.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  name = ds['name'];
});
}

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: userName.get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return const Text("Document does not exist");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Text("Full Name: ${data['name']}");
    }

    return const Text("loading");
  },
)
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `dnQ4...` value in your screenshot the UID of the user whose name you're trying to show? Because that is what you code assumes here: `.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that "FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid" doesn't give null and there is an internet connection.

Then, there are two ways:

Do the following function, and call it in initState method

```
Future<void> getUserData(String userID) async {
DocumentReference authResult =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID);
DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await authResult.get();
var data = docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
name = data['name'];
}
```

when you call this function, pass the userId as an argument to the function

**OR**

Instead of implementing a function and call it in initState you can call didChangeDependencies and make it async

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() async {
super.didChangeDependencies();
DocumentReference authResult =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID);
DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await authResult.get();
var data = docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
name = data['name'];
}
```

**Edit**

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
 }

 class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
 DocumentReference userName = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

 //Variable used to store the name
 String name = '';

@override
void didChangeDependencies() async {
super.didChangeDependencies();
DocumentReference authResult =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await authResult.get();
var data = docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
name = data['name'];
}

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: userName.get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return const Text("Document does not exist");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Text("Full Name: ${data['name']}");
    }

    return const Text("loading");
  },
)
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Comment: So how can I display didChangeDependencies in my FutureBuilder? Im new to flutter so I m little bit lost in that. Also userID is Undefined name so should I do it like  String userID = ' '; ?

Comment: I edited the solution with the full code. you can try it now :)

Comment: It still says document does not exist :/